# Returning Multiple Results of the same Variable on One Line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to go through shared mailboxes and get users who have certain access rights. I'm able to do this, however the problem is when a mailbox has multiple users with access rights.

I'll be using code for just one mailbox instead of every single one for this. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity example@domain.com | select Identity, User |
    where user -like '*@*'
```

I get this as a result:

[image: Output]

But I'd like to get something like this:

[image: Desired_Output]

Is there a way to make Users with the same Identity to be on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) to group users by mailbox, then expand the groups with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
... | Group-Object Identity |
    Select-Object @{n='Identity';e={$_.Name}},
                  @{n='User';e={$_.Group.User -join ', '}}
```

`Group-Object` groups your result objects by their `Identity` property, i.e. all objects with the same identity value are collected in one `GroupInfo` object (in its `Group` property to be precise). The `Select-Object` statement with the calculated properties then creates a new custom object for each group. The `User` calculated property expands the `User` property of the grouped objects and joins the names to a comma-separated list.

Note that you need PowerShell v3 or newer for `$_.Group.User -join ', '` to work. On earlier versions you need to replace it with something like

```
($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand User) -join ', '
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite understand it all, but it works!

Comment: Will do. Also, one other question. I'd like it to return blank if the mailbox doesn't have any full access users. It currently doesn't print anything and just skips over that mailbox. Is there a way to make the Identity still show up with nothing in the User column?